# GTK+ How to add import libraries in Visual Studio?

Tags: gtk

I installed GTK+ on Windows and I created the application using gcc. Now I want to create an application using Visual Studio. The application is compiled, but the linker needs to connect libraries. In this topic http://www.tarnyko.net/en/?q=node/22 it is proposed to add .lib files. But .lib files are not in C:\msys64\mingw64\lib. What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/ports/gtk)/MSYS2 and NuGet package GTK3 for C#. But that was a year ago and I don't remember the details. Вообщем попробуй vcpkg.